# Объединение нескольких таблиц SQL-бд SQL или Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Возникла задача и не знаю с какой стороны к ней подступиться.
Есть Postgre 
В БД есть 9 таблиц, в некоторых из них поля совпадают, в некоторых - нет.
Нужно создать три новых таблицы, в каждую из них подпихнуть по 3 существующих из этих 9. Условие: в новых таблицах должны получиться только уникальные поля. К примеру:

```
Таблица А
id | street
1  | Peshkov 
2  | Kalinina 
3  | Broken streetlights

Таблица B
id | street | height
1  | Kutuza | 30
2  | E95    | 100
3  | Lenina | 0
4  | Main   | 500

Таблица C
id | number | amount | height
1  | 5      | 55     | 101
2  | 11     | 1      | 7

Надо создать таблицу ABC, следующего вида:
id | street              | height | number | amount
1  | Peshkov             | NULL   |  NULL  | NULL
2  | Kalinina            | NULL   |  NULL  | NULL
3  | Broken streetlights | NULL   |  NULL  | NULL
4  | Kutuza              | 30     |  NULL  | NULL
5  | E95                 | 100    |  NULL  | NULL
6  | Lenina              | 0      |  NULL  | NULL
7  | Main                | 500    |  NULL  | NULL
8  |   NULL              | 101    |   5    | 55
9  |   NULL              | 7      |   11   | 1
```

Провести работу можно либо напрямую в БД менеджере через sql-запрос, либо с помощью Java на моё усмотрение. 
Подскажите, плз, в какую сторону рыть.

Залез в оф. документацию postrgre, нашёл там union!
Получается следующее:
1)Пытаюсь создать общую таблицу из трёх, прицепляя их по очереди

```
create table line as 
(
    select * from a 
    union select * from b_networks_lines 
    union select * from c
);
```

SQL Error [42601]: ОШИБКА: все запросы в UNION должны возвращать одинаковое число столбцов

Comment: на мой скромный взгляд, если Вы не знаете где лучше проводить работу, но результат будет один и тот же, то выбирайте то где Вам проще и понятнее.... еще одна мысль на которую можно операться может звучать так: если преобразование одноразовое и необратимое, то можно сделать напрямую в БД, если данная операция будет производиться многократно, то наверное лучше реализовать её в Java... опять же для точного ответа нужно понимать из чего вообще состоит Ваше приложение

Comment: DDL в приложении - в общем дурной тон. Так что итоговую таблицу создайте руками - всё равно действие-то одноразовое. И несложное. Что же до последующего заполнения - почему id из второй таблицы изменены, а из других - сохранены? Ну и просто из любопытства - а нахрена всё это делается?

Comment: id поправил - моя косяка, id - обычный автоинкремент.
Нахрена - тест от старших разработчиков на сообразительность, самообучаемость и гугление )
DDL имеется в виду класс языков для работы с бд внутри кода программы? Тогда что, гибернейт?
А если задачу будет нужно выполнять по требованию оператора, с выбором разных бд?

Comment: Для того чтобы использовать union необходимо обязательно перечислить все столбцы из первой таблицы. Затем в следующих таблицах столбцы разместить в соответсвтии с первой, при этом если столбца нет в следующей таблице то на это место вставить Null. Если общее количество столбцов больше чем в первой, то в первой нужно дополнить списко столбцов Null-ами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если задача разовая, то можно выполнить все просто запросами. На мой взгляд ваш подход верен. Просто в запросе необходимо привести в соответствие количество и порядок столбцов выбираемых в новую таблицу.
Например:

```
select 
  a.1
  null
  null
  null
 from a union 
select  
  b.1
  b.2
  null 
  null
 from b union 
select 
  null
  с.3
  c.1
  c.2 from c
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал немного дубовым способом:
1 взял самую "широкую" таблицу

```
create table abc as select * from c
```

дополнил её полями, существующими в других.

Потом инсертами зафигачил:

```
insert into abc (street, height) select street, height from b;
insert into abc (street) select street from a;
```

как-то так. 
Что делать, если полей и таблиц будет под сотню - думаю надо будет через жаву автоматизировать.